# Free tagging (term) not translated when creating a node

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I have a bundle type "article", which is translatable in 2 languages (English (=default) and French). The user can select the language when creating the article. It also has a "free tagging field", which refers to a taxonomy (Which is also translatable).

When the user creates an article in the French language, and adds a new tag (which does not exists yet), the tag is created in the default language (=English).

How can i make sure that the new tag is created in the language the user selected on the node creation page?